# Finding the index of the first match of a regular expression in Java

Tags: java, regex

EDIT: I found the answer here. [Returning the String found with a regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752215/returning-the-string-found-with-a-regular-expression)

Is there a straightforward way to get a list of all the substrings that match a regex within a string?

It should do something like this.

- Example string: `Google`
- Example regex: `(og.e)`
- What I want to obtain with this method: `ogle`

Another example.

- Example string: `Facebook`
- Example regex: `(a.o)`
  String I want to obtain with this method: `acebo`

EDIT: I've found something that might be relevant to this question. http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0360__Regular-Expression/Matchindexandvalue.htm I still don't know whether this will do what I want it to do.

Comment: 1. Do you mean Java, or do you mean JavaScript? Pick one. 2. I think you're using `*` as if it's the [Kleene star](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star), not `*` as Java, JavaScript, & co. interpret `*` in regexps. I've edited your question to correct the regexps.

Comment: This post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752215/returning-the-string-found-with-a-regular-expression has the answer

Comment: +1 For a well formulated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start learn/use java.util.regex API classes - Pattern and Matcher. For more info on regular expression read this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/).

Sample:

```
 Pattern pat=Pattern.compile("og.e");
 Matcher mat=pat.matcher("Google");
 if(mat.find())
     System.out.println(mat.start());
```

Comment: I meant to use "." instead of "*". I'll fix it in the original post.